# Definite integral of $\sin^4x$

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I solve this integral

$$\int_0^\pi \sin^4{x}\,dx\;\text{?}$$

Is beta function used to solve it? I want the way.

Comment: You don't solve integrals, you evaluate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $\,\displaystyle{I:=\int\sin^4x\,dx}\,$

Now, we have that$$\sin^4x=\sin^2x(1-\cos^2x):$$

By parts the second integral:

$$u=\cos x\;,\;u'=-\sin x$$

$$v'=\sin^2x\cos x\;,\;v=\frac{1}{3}\sin^3x\Longrightarrow$$

$$\int\sin^2x\cos^2x\,dx=\frac{1}{3}\sin^3x\cos x+\frac{1}{3}I$$

So we get that:

$$I=\int\sin^2x\,dx-\frac{1}{3}\sin^3x\cos x-\frac{1}{3}I\Longrightarrow$$

$$\Longrightarrow \frac43I=\frac{x-\sin x\cos x}2-\frac{1}{3}\sin^3x\cos x\Longrightarrow$$

$$\Longrightarrow I=\frac{3}{8}(x-\sin x\cos x)-\frac{1}{4}\sin^3x\cos x+K$$

Now do the above with your definite integral: the result is  $\,\displaystyle{\frac{3\pi}{8}}\,$

Comment: For the life of me I cannot differentiate your integral back into sin^4(x), or rather, I can differentiate it and get an answer but I cannot seem to simplify the answer to sin^4(x)

Comment: Uf, this is ancient history...but thanks to your comment I just discovered a typo: three lines before the last one, where on the left hand we have $\;\frac43 I\;$ , on the right hand the second member must be $\;-\frac13\sin^3x\cos x\;$ and **not** "+", as it is obvious from the line above that one ! Thus we must get at the end $$I=\frac38(x-\sin x\cos x)\color{red}-\frac14\sin^3x\cos x$$ Try now, it must be almost straightforward to check. Thanks. Editing.

Comment: Ah, now I can simplify and it seems correct

Answer (score 4):

"Hint":

$$\int \sin^4(x)dx=\int [\sin^2(x)]^2dx=\frac{1}{4}\int(1-\cos(2x))^2dx$$

Comment: To continue, you FOIL out the square and then use $\cos^2(2x)=\frac{1}{2}(1+2\cos(4x))$...

Answer (score 1):

Beta function formula (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function )
$$
\mathrm{B}(x,y) = 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} (\sin\theta)^{2x-1}(\cos\theta)^{2y-1}d\theta
$$
Perhaps that is what you need to use?